# Why does cat urine have a stronger smell than other pet urine?

Tags: cats, toilet-training, cleaning

It may just be my perception, but it seems like cat pee has a distinctly 'Cat' smell that is different from other pet urine.  It seems to have a stronger smell that lasts longer, than other urine smells.

What is it about cat urine that gives it the extra strong and long lived odor?

Answer (score 2):

Cats are descended from desert dwelling animals and have their kidneys concentrate the urine very strongly to recover water.  This is why they tend to have kidney issues in old age.

Answer (score 1):

This table from [Cornell University](https://ahdc.vet.cornell.edu/Sects/ClinPath/modules/ua-rout/sg.htm) lists the [specific gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_gravity) of urine for dogs, cats, and large animals.

[image: Canine sg usual range 1.015-1.045. Feline sg usual range 1.035-1.060. Large animals sp usual range 1.015-1.030]

Cats usually have the highest urinary specific gravity. Since urine is composed of water and waste material, a higher specific gravity means that cat urine has a higher amount of waste material (the smelly stuff) per volume excreted.

Comment: What is the extra "Smelly stuff" that cats have that others don't?  Is cat urine just more concentrated of the same stuff, or does it actually have more stuff?

Comment: @JamesJenkins I couldn't find any evidence of it being different stuff, only that it's specific gravity is higher so there's more of it.

Comment: [This - Due to the uric acid component of cat urine, cat pee has a half-life of six years.](http://catcentric.org/care-and-health/removing-cat-urine/) or something similar was part of what got me thinking that the "stuff" must be different.  From my own experience, it seems like cat and dog pee have distinctly different smells, and I have been in many houses that have been unoccupied for some time, where it smells like cat pee.  I have only been in one unoccupied house that smelled like dog pee (*it was a special case, where really bad choices were made*)

Comment: Also [example - Cat urine is the most durable substance on the planet. It has a half life of a jillion years. Far far worse than dog pee](http://www.city-data.com/forum/new-jersey/794216-need-advice-about-purchasing-house-smells.html)

Comment: @JamesJenkins this site says that dog urine has more uric acid than cat urine (even w/o correcting for specific gravity) http://www.2ndchance.info/normaldogandcatbloodvalues.htm

Comment: the "smelly stuff" is mostly simple nitrogen compounds such as urea (which can become ammonia and other things).

Answer (score 1):

Ammonia is root of the odor in cat urine.

Ammonia as a solid crystallizes into symmetrical cubics.  It's also miscible with water and can be boiled off.

In animals it typically binds with an acid and becomes urea and is a key component to reduction of pH levels in organisms.

Vinegar helps to break down urea into its base components for cleaning purposes.  Baking soda (sodium bicarbonate) neutralizes any acid.  Bulk sodium bicarbonate can be purchased as soda ash and is relatively inexpensive compared to grocery store baking soda.  Pool supply retailers will carry this as it is used to reduce acidity level in swimming pools.